# vba: save workbook as csv file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save a workbook specified using a workbook object as file format csv but having a few problems. In the below code, I get an error after the save-as line, saying the .csv file is read-only:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim c As Workbook
    Set c = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Testing\testbook.xlsx", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
    Call sSaveWorkbookAsCSV(c, "C:\Testing")
End Sub

Public Sub WBookToCSV(wkbktosv As Workbook, strOutputFilePath As String)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call wkbktosv.SaveAs(strOutputFilePath, xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Call wkbktosv.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked if a file named c:\testing\testbook.csv exists and is read only?

Comment: The csv file doesn't get created. The .xlsx file exists and is not read only

Comment: oh, sorry, I misread your code.  You are trying to save with the name c:\testing.csv.  Maybe that one exists and is read only?

Comment: That code is trying to save the CSV as `c:\Testing` not `c:\Testing.csv` and as there's a folder with that name already it's going to fail.

As it happens it's a handy trick I use (in reverse) to prevent google chrome from installing into people's profiles when they weren't expecting it.

Comment: for testing, comment out the `Application.DisplayAlerts`. Also, the `.SaveAs` has a filename, not a filepath as the first parameter:   expression.SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it to: sSaveWorkbookAsCSV(c, "C:\Testing.csv")